# How to identify meeting workspaces in a SharePoint site, using client side coding or OOTB?

Tags: meeting-workspace, content-migration

I have around 400 SharePoint sites, which needs to be migrated to Sp2013. But before migration I need to identify how many of the site collections or sub-sites contains meeting workspaces, so that those sites can be categorized as a complex sites.

Is there anyway, we can identify how many meeting workspaces a site or subsites has by client side programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each site collection, you can list SPWeb templates using these scripts.

**Client side PowerShell**

```
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("yoursharepoint.com")

$web = $ctx.Web
$ctx.Load($web.Webs)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
foreach($subweb in $web.Webs)
{
    Write-Host "$($subweb.Url) --> $($subweb.WebTemplate)"
}
```

**Server side PowerShell**

```
$site = Get-SPSite https://yoursharepoint.com

foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    Write-Host "$($web.Url) --> $($web.WebTemplate)"
}
```

All templates starting with MPS are meeting workspaces (list of template codes [here](http://www.funwithsharepoint.com/sharepoint-2013-site-templates-codes-for-powershell/)).

Comment: for some reason I am not able to execute client side powershell, can the same be achieved through client object model programming?